# How to change the video source link according to time in HTML video player?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to make a video player and it is supposed to change the video source by given time. For ex: At "12 AM" I want to play this video source "video1.mp4" and at "1 AM" I want to play this source "video2.mp4" and at "5 PM" I want to play this "video3.mp4".

I have just started it and I am new to this field so I don't have idea how can I do that, I think we have to write a JS Code?
Can someone let me know how can we do that?

```html
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

This the only code I have written

Comment: java ≠ javascript.  They’re two very different languages and runtimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls id="player">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

```js
var d = new Date(); // get date 
var h = d.getHours(); // get hour in 24

var player = document.getElementById('player');

switch (h) {
  case 12:
    player.src = 'movie.mp4';
    break;
  case 1:
    player.src = 'movie2.mp4';
    break;
  case 17:
    player.src = 'movie3.mp4';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**change your code:**

**html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
    
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="source">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

**js:**

```
    const source=document.getElementById("source");
    function change_source(time){
      switch(time) {
        case '1 AM':
          source.setAttribute("src","movie.mp4")
          break;
        case '2 AM':
          source.setAttribute("src","movie2.mp4")
          break;
        default:
         // code block
     }
   }
```

**good luck**